# Perl: Read MANIFEST.MF file from Java .jar file

Tags: perl, jar, header, zip, manifest

I'm trying to figure out how to read the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file form a java jar file in perl. I'm attempting to use [Mail::Header](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mail::Header) in order to separate the properties in the manifest. This works fine if the manifest file is already extracted from the jar, but I'm trying to figure out how to extract the manifest into memory and then immediately put into a Header object. This is what I have so far:

```
my $jarFile = "MyJar.jar";
my &jar = Archive::Zip->new($jarFile);

my $manifest = Archive::Zip::MemberRead->new($jar, "META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");

my $header = Mail::Header->new;
$header->read(????);

print $header->get("Class-Path");
```

I can't figure out which constructor and/or which extract/read function to use to read the $manifest file handle. (I'm new to perl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MemberRead`](http://p3rl.org/Archive::Zip::MemberRead) has a really dumb API. It should give a **real** handle, or at least mimic `IO::File` in a compatible fashion (so we pass it to the `Mail::Header` constructor or at least be able to call the [`getlines` method](http://p3rl.org/IO::Handle#%24io-%3Egetlines)), but doesn't.

We can work around its incompatibility by storing the file content temporarily in an array.

```
my @lines;
{
    my $handle = Archive::Zip->new($jar_file)->memberNamed('META-INF/MANIFEST.MF')->readFileHandle;
    while (defined(my $line = $handle->getline)) { # even $_ doesn't work!! what a piece of camel dung
        push @lines, $line;
    }
}

my $headers = Mail::Header->new([@lines]);
print $headers->get('Class-Path');
```

Comment: Thanks daxim. Works for me. The only other problem I had with what I was trying to do was a parsing issue with the list of *.jar files. The manifest adds extra spaces in random spots of the list so this is what I did to get a list of jar files separated by ':'.

join(".jar:", split(".jar", join("", split(" ", $headers->get("Class-Path"))))).".jar";